# Groups generated by the subset of integer powers of group elements.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, finitely-generated

I am intrigued by the following question about finite groups. Given a group $G$ with elements $\{g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_n\}$, do there exist interesting sufficient conditions such that the group generated by the subset of some fixed integer power of the elements of the group, e.g., $S^m \equiv \{g_1^m, g_2^m, \cdots, g_n^m\}$ is a non-trivial proper subgroup $\langle S^m \rangle = G^\prime < G$?

There are many simple examples of this, e.g., among Abelian groups for any $m \,\lvert\, n$, or the symmetric group on $k$ elements for $m = 2$, etc., but I am looking for a more general principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens whenever $G$ admits a quotient group $G/N$ of order $m$ (equivalently, a normal subgroup of index $m$), since every $m^{th}$ power is zero in this quotient by Lagrange's theorem and so the subgroup generated by the $m^{th}$ powers is contained in $N$. This explains both the abelian case and the case of the symmetric groups with $m = 2$.

Somewhat more generally, $G/H$ can have [exponent](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) $m$. This explains further cases such as the case that $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $m = p$; in this case we can take the quotient given by the [Frattini subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini_subgroup).

Comment: By admits a quotient group $G/H$ do you mean exhibits a subgroup isomorphic to $G/H$? This is a pretty strong condition.

Comment: @pedalferrous: no, I mean what I wrote, that it admits a quotient group $G/H$. Maybe it would be clearer if I wrote $G/N$? I mean $N$ is a normal subgroup of index $m$.

Comment: If the group admits two distinct normal subgroups of identical index, for instance, how should one characterize the group generated by powers of group elements to this index?Or rather, is it correct to say that this property is dependent only on the index of $N$.

Comment: @pedalferrous: the argument applies to every normal subgroup of index $m$ and the conclusion is that the subgroup generated by the $m^{th}$ powers is in the intersection of all such subgroups. Note also that the subgroup generated by the $m^{th}$ powers is automatically normal, and the quotient by it is, more or less by definition, the universal quotient of $G$ which has exponent dividing $m$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations so far. For what situations can we assert that $\langle S^m \rangle = N$? Moreover, $m$ for which there is no index $m$ normal subgroup are seemingly not forbidden from generating proper subgroups $\langle S^m \rangle < G$, though this subgroup is still normal and must have index $m^\prime$ s.t. $ m \lvert m^\prime$, I suppose.

Comment: @pedalferrous: what is $N$ in your question? And yes, what I described is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one. A necessary and sufficient condition for $\langle G^m \rangle$ to be a proper subgroup is that there exists a proper quotient which has exponent dividing $m$ (and, again, this is just because the quotient by $\langle G^m \rangle$ is tautologically the universal such quotient) but that's harder to check.